# Как связаться с WooCommerce REST API используя обычные fetch запросы?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, woocommerce, авторизация

Я пытаюсь связаться с WooCommerce REST API с помощью fetch запросов в  react. Это работает, если я использую consumer_key и consumer_secret прямо в строке запроса:

```
https://my-site.ru/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_817d29ef4g409b34п5e215d66e98cfeeb80982f1&consumer_secret=cs_880b76d36h204b32471f328c014а4c081ca03223
```

Но если я попытаюсь каким-либо образом вставить ключи в тело запроса, он вернет ошибку 401. Я пробовал по-разному, но, видимо, я прописываю что-то не так.

Все примеры в Google используются с модулем @woocommerce-rest-api, который по некоторым причинам я не могу использовать.

Пробовал так же стандартное обращение через oauth 1.0. Не работает

```
    let WooCommerce = {
url:  'https://my-site.ru', // Your store URL
Authorization : 'oauth 1.0',
consumer_key: 'ck_817d29ef45609b3738e215d66e98cfeeb80982f1', // Your consumer secret
consumer_secret: 'cs_880b76d31м304b32471f328c0ce44c081ca03223', // Your consumer secret
ssl: true,
version: 'wc/v3',
wpAPI: true,
queryStringAuth: true };
```

Подскажите, как правильно указать ключи в теле запроса fetch, чтобы REST API их принимал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Это не возможно. WooCommerce REST API настроен так, что принимает ключи только как параметры прямо в строке запроса. Из-за такого поведения пришлось создавать небольшой сервер и общаться с Woo через него, что бы ключи не увели. Ключи соответственно хранятся на сервере.